# Calculating self-induction current at specific time

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, induction

I've been studying Circuit Analysis, and there was this problem I don't know how to solve. I don't know if this kind of question does not fit to this site's format. I'm sorry if it doesn't but I need answer as soon as possible because there is exam and the first place I could ask was here. I need to see how it is solved.

[image: Circuit]

The switch opens at \$ t = 0 \$ . Find \$ i_{1}(t) \$ for \$ t > 0 \$.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and be more specific with where you are getting stuck. The community will not solve your homework problems for you.

Comment: OK - start by telling us what you think will happen if the switch is open for a while, and then you close it.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. The instructor will ask question very similar to these. So even if I don't completely understand I can memorise the solution path.

Comment: @Haggra I suggest not to do that since it will be easier to trick you if you just memorise the answer and professors love to do that...

Comment: You need to demonstrate some kind of effort or solution on this site, you won't make it as an engineer if you can't solve problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because academic problem with no attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I1(t) = I10 * exp(-t/tau) t > 0

I10 = V/(R1//R2) * R1/(R1+R2)

tau = L/(R1+R2)

R1 = 6 Ohm

R2 = 12 Ohm

This is the solution, it is very mechanical, but try to think it through. The circuit is stationary for t < 0 so the inductor is equivalent to a short circuit. At t = 0 the switch opens, the current in the inductor cannot change suddently (that would imply a finite change in energy has occurred in an infinitesimal time), then you have a current circulating in a resistive circuit, it will eventually dissipate all the available energy (which was stored in the inductor). How fast? that depends on the time constant of the circuit.

Since all the remaining sources are stationary (there are no other current/voltage sources) the final solution is stationary and you can calculate that by simply considering the inductor a short circuit in the circuit at time > 0. But in this case it is pretty obvious that the current is going to go to zero.

Comment: But the answer is e^(-9t) A.

Comment: @Haggra My bad, the equivalent resistance from the point of view of the inductor at time t>0 is the series of the two, not the parallel.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you. I appreciate your help a lot. It was the only one I couldn't do. So happy right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

AT t<0 (switch closed) steadystate is:
I1(t <0) = 1 A
I2(t <0) = 2 A
V(L) is zero (perfect inductor)

At t=0 (the instant the switch opens)
I1(0) = 1 A
Therefore I2 = 1 A (current has to flow from terminal to terminal on L through R1+R2)
V(L) = I * R = 1 * 18 = -18 V (wrt 12 V ground)
Current/Voltage decay:
tau = L/R1+R2 = 2/18 = 0.11 S

You can run a simulation for the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3jiJK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Results showing initial time to steadystate (t<0) and switch then opens:

[image]